# Spring Boot: Completely Ignore All Datasources During Unit Tests

Tags: spring-boot

I have all kinds of unit tests that mock the repositories they would otherwise need to connect to, yet Spring Boot insists on trying to connect to them.

I've scoured this place, and have seen the suggestions to exclude all the different autoconfiguration classes from each and every one of the test classes I have (or do it globally in /src/test/resources/application.properties) but that doesn't stop Spring Boot from trying to get some kind of data sources going. It seems to just starve it for the stuff it needs to get those datasources going. There doesn't seem to be anything I can do to tell Spring Boot "Do absolutely nothing involving trying to connect to datasources at any time".

I want to be able to do this so I can write and run unit tests on code when I'm not connected to a network. I've considered running H2 and that Flapdoodle whatever, but I've heard that Flapdoodle has problems with later builds of Spring Boot these days, and the H2 module hasn't been updated since 2019.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Here's a sample test, complete with the exclusions:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SweepsServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private SweepsService sweepsService;

    @Mock
    private PrizeEntryRepository mockPrizeEntryRepository;

    @Mock
    private PrizeRepositoryPrimary mockPrizeRepositoryPrimary;

    @Mock
    private PrizeRepositorySecondary mockPrizeRepositorySecondary;

    @Mock
    private PointService mockPointService;

    private final String prizeId = "prize1";
    private final String awardId = "award1";
    private final int userId = 1234;
    private final int costToEnter = 25;
    private final int maxEntriesPerUser = 1;
    private final int numberToPurchase = 1;

    @Test
    public void givenPrizeNotFound_whenProcessSweepsEntry_thenThrowException() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(userId);
        Mockito.when(mockPrizeRepositoryPrimary.findById(prizeId)).thenReturn(Optional.empty());
        assertThatIllegalArgumentException().isThrownBy(
                () -> sweepsService.processSweepsEntry(prizeId, "RAFFLE", null, null, user, numberToPurchase)
        ).withMessage("User " + user.getId() + " tried to enter sweepstakes id " + prizeId + " but that ID was not found.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered removing the `@SpringBootTest` annotation altogether? Considering you mock everything and you don't need the application context it seems like a sensible thing to do. Just use JUnit and Mockito.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't need to build a spring application context (in case of unit tests) just refrain from using the `@SpringBootTest` annotation and use `JUnit` and `Mockito` exclusively. Otherwise, in case of integration tests, for example, I usually just define which configuration classes I want to include explicitly:

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = {SomeConfigurationClass.class, AnotherConfigurationClass.class})
class SomeIntegrationTest { ... }
```

See the JavaDoc for [`SpringbootTest#classes`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html#classes--):

> The component classes to use for loading an ApplicationContext. Can also be specified using @ContextConfiguration(classes=...). **If no explicit classes are defined the test will look for nested @Configuration classes, before falling back to a @SpringBootConfiguration search**.