# Spring - contextLoads() method is failing

Tags: spring, spring-boot

My Spring app runs fine but when I try to run the test contextLoads method I'm getting this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@37496720 testClass = com.cookbookbackend.CookbookBackendApplicationTests, locations = [], classes = [com.cookbookbackend.CookbookBackendApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@48aca48b, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@72e5a8e, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@6fdbe764, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@298a5e20, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@2b8500b9], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]

I'm also getting this error for ApplicationTests

> Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=${DB_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.</groupId>
    <artifactId>cookbook-backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cookbook-backend</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is the ApplicationTests.java

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class CookbookBackendApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Comment: Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67729217/spring-boot-completely-ignore-all-datasources-during-unit-tests), it seems that you are loading any configuration class existing in the classpath during the test execution. Perhaps try to define your test sample config class to avoid the auto scan.